# How to connect and authenticate an Android app to a Rails server?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, facebook-login, google-signin

I have and Android app that needs a chat application. I've opted to develop my chat application using `Rails 5` and `Action Cable` (and it works just fine) and make my chat as a WebView in Android using `Turbolinks 5`.

My problem now is to connect my Android application to my Rails server. In Android I have `Facebook` and `Google` login. How can I pass my user information to Rails in order to authenticate and save them to the database and show their names and pictures in my Chat view?

Comment: Have you tried `devise-token-auth?

Comment: You need first decide authentication flow and then write REST APIs fro the both applications to interact.

Comment: @AndreyS, I've looked at it and I think the best way is to go with it, but I'm lost on how to start implemeting. Do you have any piece of code to guide me?